# Create a transform stream on process.stdin compatible with child_process stdio

Tags: node.js, node-streams

`child_process::spawn(...)` and accepts a `stream` to stdio. For example: `{ stdio: [Stream /* hereby "child stream" */, 'inherit', 'inherit'] }` with constraints on the stream interface for `stdin`.

I want to transform my process' `stdin` and pipe it to a child_process. I transform my content using a transform stream. However, the child stream needs to be both a `TTY` and have a backing `fd`, otherwise node.js will not accept it.

For example:

```js
// node + the os demand a filedescriptor (fd),
// so let's get one
this._stdinfd = await fs.open("foo", "w+");

// pretend we have a real transform operation here :)
const myTransform = new node_stream_1.Transform({
    transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        callback(null, chunk);
    },
});

// process.stdin is a Socket... so to best emulate stdin, let's
// make our transform stream also pipe thru a Socket
const mySocket = new node_net_1.Socket({ fd: this._stdinfd.fd });
// ^ but node hates this :)

process.stdin.pipe(myTransform).pipe(mySocket);
const proc = child_process_1.default.spawn("tmux", {
    stdio: [mySocket, "inherit", "inherit"],
});
```

This and similar variants fail. I'm not clear on the best way to to stitch the required primitives together. Let me know your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

Use "pipe" instead of passing the stream directly into the stdio array:

```js
spawn("cat", {
    stdio: [
        "pipe",
        "inherit",
        "inherit"
    ]
});
```

Then use the child returned object and access "stdin", at index 0:

```js
transform.pipe(child.stdio[0]);
```

Full example:

```js
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
const { Transform } = require("stream");

const transform = new Transform({
    transform(chunk, enc, cb) {

        chunk = chunk.toString();
        chunk = chunk.toUpperCase();

        cb(null, chunk);

    }
});


const child = spawn("cat", {
    stdio: [
        "pipe",
        "inherit",
        "inherit"
    ]
});

transform.pipe(child.stdio[0]);
transform.write("Hello World");
```

The example above simple converts the transform writable input to uppercase string and push that into the readable queue, which is pipe into the child process stdin.

Comment: Thanks for the write up, but this solution explicitly does not work for my case. Why? Because the child needs a TTY attached to it. I’m passing the stream to tmux. If. tmux does not get a tty stream, it doesn’t launch. For this reason, my question was specifically about creating the stream, and passing it in, rather than extracting it from the returned child process handle. Apologies, I could’ve perhaps added more detail upfront.